# Stockfish Depth 2 the same as Depth 1?

Tags: stockfish

I noticed that Stockfish Depth 2 has exactly the same evaluation as at Depth 1 (see Arena output below). The number of nodes increases so something appears to be a bit inconsistent. I would have expected Depth 1 to be the evaluation of the net and then Depth 2 the first one where a search is performed but this is not the case it seems. The analysis is performed on the starting position with Stockfish 16 using 1 thread.

```
Analysis of C:\Z\StartingPos_1p.epd   
19-Dec-23 16:35:29 Level: 3 Ply
Analyzing engine: SF16

 1 - 0 1                
    Avoid move: 
    Best move (SF16): g2-g4
    Not found in: 00:00
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.26   1.e4
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.18   1.e3
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.07   1.h3
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.04   1.d3
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.04   1.c4
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.03   1.c3  e5
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    +0.02   1.Nf3
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.06   1.a4  e5
     3/2    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.08   1.d4
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.25   1.b3  Nf6
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.39   1.h4
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.39   1.Nh3  e6
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.60   1.a3  d5
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.63   1.f3
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.65   1.Na3
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.70   1.b4
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -0.72   1.Nc3  e5
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -1.04   1.f4  Nh6
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -1.15   1.g4  d5
     3/3    00:00.003            916    305k    -1.24   1.g3  d5
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    +0.02   1.Nf3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.08   1.d4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.08   1.e4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.16   1.e3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.25   1.a3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.28   1.c3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.30   1.g3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.30   1.d3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.32   1.h3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.33   1.Nh3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.35   1.Nc3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.38   1.c4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.39   1.h4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.39   1.a4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.46   1.b3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.52   1.f4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.63   1.f3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.65   1.Na3
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.70   1.b4
     2/2    00:00.001            457    457k    -0.78   1.g4
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    +0.02   1.Nf3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.08   1.d4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.08   1.e4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.16   1.e3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.25   1.a3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.28   1.c3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.30   1.g3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.30   1.d3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.32   1.h3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.33   1.Nh3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.35   1.Nc3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.38   1.c4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.39   1.h4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.39   1.a4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.46   1.b3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.52   1.f4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.63   1.f3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.65   1.Na3
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.70   1.b4
     1/1    00:00.001            247    247k    -0.78   1.g4
```